# Highcharts component that creates secondary yAxis based on props.boolean

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm creating a Highstock component with Highcharts using react wrapper. I want to enable a parameter to add a secondary `yAxis`. This is how my component is structured:

```js
class BasicSeriesChart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { data } = this.props;
    const doubleYAxis = this.props;
  }
  const secondaryYAxis = { // Secondary yAxis
      id: 1,
    };

  this.state = {
    chartOptions: {
      series: data.map((set, index) => ({
      ...set,
      yAxis: doubleYAxis ? secondaryYAxis.id: 0,
      })
    }
  };
  render() {
  const { chartOptions } = this.state;

    return (
      <HighchartsReact
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        constructorType="stockChart"
        options={chartOptions}
        allowChartUpdate
      />
    );
  }
}

BasicSeriesChart.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  doubleYAxis: PropTypes.bool,
};

export default BasicSeriesChart;
```

I'm calling it on a separate file:

```js
const doubleYAxis = true;
const chartData = mockData.map((series) => ({
  ...series,
  }));

function HighStock() {

  return(
    <BasicSeriesChart
      data={chartData}
      doubleYAxis={doubleYAxis}
    />
  );
}

export default HighStock;
```

To enable a secondary `yAxis` I know I can define `chartOptions.yAxis` with an array of objects instead of a single object, but I need to make it refactorable, my approach is to call the `addAxis` method.

My logic is, check the `doubleYAxis` and if `true` add the secondary Axis `chart.addAxis(secondaryYAxis);`, but where should I call that function on my component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setState` to manipulate the number of axes, for example:

```
toggleAxis(){
  this.setState({
    chartOptions: {
      yAxis: this.state.chartOptions.yAxis.length === 2 ? 
        [{}] : 
        [{}, {}]
    }
  });
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-5q9db